# How to add multiple domain to a single website (linux hosting)

Tags: dns, web, web-hosting, nameservers

I have a single website but two different domain names. I have registered xyz.com and now want xyz.abc.com (a subdomain of abc.com) to point to the same website ie xyz.com. Now I came to know that I need need to change the DNS of abc.com. I got the IP address of my website. How to change DNS of a subdomain? Please help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: If two domain names share one IP address, there is no problem. Your website could be reached by both of domain names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have for 1 ip only one domain with subdomains. That is, if you have a site abc.com, you can have many subdomains type xyz.abc.com, but not xyz.com.

What DNS  software you use?